# Why does express's default error handler behaviour return stack traces to the client?

Tags: node.js, error-handling, express, crash

I'm trying to get the error handling in my http api server working correctly, and I don't understand node's error handling behaviour.

I've defined my own error object like so:

```
function ServerError(statusCode, err, message) {
    this.status = statusCode;

    if (err != undefined) {
        this.err = err;

        if (message != undefined) {
            this.message = message;
        }
        else {
            this.message = err.message || err;
        }
    }
}

ServerError.prototype = new Error();
```

I use this object like so, either in middleware or a handler:

```
function forceError() {
    return function(req, res, next) {
        next(new ServerError(500, "Internal error!"));
    }
}
```

Without any handler defined, this error gets printed to the console *and* is returned in the response body. This happens for things like `TypeErrors` as well as my own errors. This is bad, as it includes a stack trace and filenames/paths.

Why is express returning the stacktrace? I thought the default behaviour was just to crash, and so not leak any information on the server to clients.

Answer (score 10):

From your code and use of `next`, I assume you are using express, and so, this is rather an express question. Express will default to serving errors with stacktraces in development mode only, while logging, but not serving, them in production mode.

Try running your app in production mode:

```
$ NODE_ENV=production node app.js
```

Comment: Yup, that stops it returning stack traces, but it's not crashing when a TypeError happens...